# Listing two or more variables alongside each other

Tags: spss

I want an alternative to running frequency for string variables because I also want to get a case number for each of the string value (I have a separate variable for case ID).

After reviewing the string values I will need to find them to recode which is the reason I need to know the case number.

I know that PRINT command should do what I want but I get an error - is there any alternative?

```
PRINT /  id var2 .
EXECUTE.


>Error # 4743.  Command name: PRINT
>The line width specified exceeds the output page width or the record length or
>the maximum record length of 2147483647.  Reduce the number of variables or
>split the output line into several records.
>Execution of this command stops.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`LIST`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_20.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_list_overview.htm?lang=en) command.

I often use the TEMPORARY commond prior to the LIST command, as often there is only a small select of record of interest I may want to "list"/investigate.

For example, in the below, only to list the records where VAR2 is not a blank string.

```
TEMP.
SELECT IF (len(VAR2)>0).
LIST ID VAR2.
```

Alternatively, you could also (but dependent on having `CUSTOM TABLES` add-on module), do something like below which would get the results into a tabular format also (which may be preferable if then exporting to Excel, for example.

```
CTABLES /TABLE CTABLES /VLABELS VARIABLES=ALL DISPLAY=NONE
  /TABLE A[C]>B[C]
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=ALL EMPTY=EXCLUDE.
```

Comment: Thanks, I remember I tried working with LIST command but the problem is that it displays all values and most of them are missing! Very hard to work with. And because this is a string I couldn't find a way to filter missing values out.

Comment: The `TEMP/SELECT IF` should solve that, shouldn't it not? If applying the appropriate filter criteria?

Comment: I think so but it didn't! But I've now changed >0 to >1 and it works wonders. Many thanks!I don't suppose it is possible to have the result in one line like PRINT would do? LIST lists variables one below the other

Comment: `CTABLES` should give you a little more control on your desired output required?

Comment: CTABLES cost too much but nevermind, thanks for your help

Comment: Far from a sales rep for SPSS myself, but it is well worth it.

Comment: The `CTABLES` command here I think will be pretty similar to what `SUMMARIZE` would spit out.

Comment: SUMMARIZE is probably your best bet.  CTABLES is intended for aggregates, not case listings